# Filling fields on Microsoft Word based on the value in a Combo Box in MS Access 2007?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-word

**Summary**: My company sends out a word document to customers and a very limited amount of the things change between different letters sent out. I want to write a macro or form on MS Access that fill in different text form fields in a word document.

**Problem**: Users use a Combo Box in MS Access 2007. I am hoping to get some insight into the best way to populate text boxes and navigate the word document.

**Question**: Is it possible to populate text boxes on Word based on the value in a Combo Box in MS Access 2007?

Comment: Do you know about the mail merge in Word? Getting the data lined up in Access via a combo box is easy and picking it up in Word shouldn't be a problem. Are you looking to launch Word and execute the merge from Access after the combo box selection is made?

Comment: Thank you for reply. yes, mail merge is what my company is using. Yes, sir. You are correct. Any idea to manipulate the pick up data from Access to Word would be appreciated! @JohnMo